# How to get type of LIveTile on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, live-tile

I want to write a method which will change the main tile in my Windows Phone 8.

To access the main tile I'm using

```
var tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();
```

But how do I know the type (Flip, Cycle, Iconic) of this tile? Because if I want to update the tile with

```
tile.Update(...);
```

And if I use the wrong type I will get an exception.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

2 ideas you could try are:

1) Try/Catch the Update call and fallback to replacing the tile (delete the existing one)
  See this [blogpost](http://www.kodyaz.com/windows-phone-8/shelltile-update-exception-template-type-mismatch.aspx).

2) Or add a query parameter in the NavigationUri like "&tileType=Cyclic" when creating it and then lookup for that parameter in the same property when updating it. See [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Live_Tile_Templates_in_Windows_Phone_8).

Very weird though that the API does not expose any obvious way for someone to figure this out.